# Using SQL to calculate CDF of SO Reputation

Tags: sql

I came across [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356050/number-of-users-with-reputation-n#graph) query to compute the CDF of SO reputation:

```
SELECT 
  Reputation, 
  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(
    ORDER BY Reputation 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS UserCount
FROM 
  Users
GROUP BY Reputation
ORDER BY Reputation
```

I crafted my own query which looks like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1265448#graph):

```
select reputation, cume_dist() over (order by reputation)
from users 
group BY reputation
order by reputation;
```

I don't think the results of these two are the same. I think there is a bug in query #2 but not able to find it. Wondering if anyone could explain why these two are returning different results.

Comment: Well... `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default "window frame". You can safely remove that to make the query simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The correct [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1265631/cdf-of-so-reputation#resultSets) is as follows:

```
with cte as (select reputation, cume_dist() over (order by reputation) as cdf
from users)
select reputation, max(cdf) from cte
group by reputation
order by reputation;
```

According to this,

- 71% of users have reputation <= 1
- 74% of users have reputation <= 10
- 92% of users have reputation <= 100
- 98% of users have reputation <= 1,000
- 99.8% of users have reputation <= 10,000